# Как исправить подготовленный MySQL Select запрос?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

В результате выполнения получаю лишь одну цену вместо списка цен на указанные в запросе даты.

```
$start = 2019-08-10;
$end = 2019-09-09;

/* создаём подготавливаемый запрос */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT coin_price FROM BTC WHERE DATE(p_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?")) {

/* связываем параметры с метками */
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $start, $end);

/* запускаем запрос */
$stmt->execute();

/* связываем переменные с результатами запроса */
$stmt->bind_result($coin_price);

/* получаем значения */
$stmt->fetch();

//printf("%s находится в округе %s\n", $start, $end, $coin_price);



$directors = array( $coin_price );

foreach ( $directors as $director ) {
 echo $director . "<br />";
}


/* закрываем запрос */
$stmt->close();
}

/* закрываем соединение */
$mysqli->close();
```

Где в подготовленном запросе допустил ошибку?

Как верно написать подготовленный запрос, чтобы получить необходимые данные из базы соответствующие промежутку между двумя датами?

Спасибо!

Comment: Так Вы фетчите одну запись - и на это успокаиваетесь. А надо в цикле тянуть, пока  тянется... или сразу всё выгребать в массив.

Comment: Да, либо fetchAll - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php либо в цикле fetchAssoc https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php  или в цикле  fetch https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-result-examples

Comment: Фуф, буду разбираться, спасибо. Ранее работал только с INSERT INTO с подготовленными запросами, Select сложно создать.